# How to get Npgsql to connect to Postgresql 9.5

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono, npgsql

I have a Debian Jessie (i386) machine with mono-complete, mono-xsp, and postgresql-9.5 (From http://apt.postgresql.org/)

I have a simple gridview hello,world style page.
Here is an excerpt from Web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Npgsql, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
           invariant="Npgsql"
           support="FF"
           description ="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
           type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="100" traceMode="SortByTime" />
</system.web>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SqlDataSource1" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1,5432;Database=test;User ID=user;Password=password;" providerName="Npgsql"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

(changing the Version to "4.0.0.0" in the assembly line makes no difference)

I get the following exception:

> System.IO.IOException
>
> Connection lost
>
> Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
>
> Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): Mono.Data.Tds.
>
> Exception stack trace:
>     at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm.GetPhysicalPacketHeader () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm.GetPhysicalPacket () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm.GetByte () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.ProcessSubPacket () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.NextResult () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.SkipToEnd () [0x00000] in :0

The postgresql log shows the following:

> [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet

Anyone out there have an idea where I should start looking for problems?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
It turns out I had omitted the ProviderName attribute on the asp:SqlDataSource tag.

A proper asp:SqlDataSource tag (4.0) looks like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr2 %>" ProviderName="Npgsql" runat="server" SelectCommand="select * from test"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The relevant Web.config entries:

```
....
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
     <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
          invariant="Npgsql"
          support="FF"
          description ="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
          type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
...
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnStr2" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=database;User ID=user;Password=password;" providerName="Npgsql"/>
```